# Wordpress plugin pulls latest posts from Xenforo, but links to thread rather than post

Tags: wordpress, posts, xenforo

this is my first posting here, so if I'm doing anything wrong, let me know!

I am working with both Wordpress and Xenforo, using WP as a portal page. They both have their own database. I'm using a WP plugin that has not continued support for years, specifically designed for Xenforo.

Problem: the plugin pulls Latest posts (or Most Recent posts) from the Xenforo forum and displays them in a sidebar widget on WP. But the posts links lead to the THREAD and not the specific POST.

I looked through the plugin's code to try and find which portion of the code I would have to modify to correct this. I have no idea what to look for.

Here is the plugin's code :

```
   <?php
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//status:               CHECKED IN
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * qry_lastposts.php:    run the query to get the last posts
 * @package plugins_lastposts
 * @version version 1.4.0
 * @copyright EIP Software LLC - eipSoftware_Copyright.php
 */
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * Get Last Posts --> run the queries to get the latest forum posts
 * @return string last post query 
 */
function qry_LastPostList($userOptions)
{
    try
    {
        $qry_sql =  "   SELECT  thread.thread_id,
                                thread.title, 
                                thread.username                 as threadstarter,
                                thread.user_id                  as threadstarterid,
                                thread.reply_count              as replies,
                                thread.last_post_id             as lastpostid,
                                thread.last_post_username       as lastposter,
                                thread.last_post_user_id        as lastposteruserid,
                                thread.last_post_date           as lastpostdate,
                                usr.avatar_date                 as lastposteravatardate,
                                TRUNCATE(usr.user_id, -3)/1000  as lastposteravatardir

                        FROM    xf_thread                   as thread
                                inner join xf_user          as usr
                                on thread.last_post_user_id = usr.user_id

                        WHERE   thread.discussion_state = 1
                                AND usr.message_count >= " . $userOptions['forumUserPosts'] . "
                                AND node_id NOT IN  (" . $userOptions['excludeNodes'] . ")
                                AND thread.last_post_date >=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL " . $userOptions['forumLookBack'] . " DAY))
                                AND usr.user_group_id NOT IN (" . $userOptions['forumUserGroup'] .")  
                        ORDER BY last_post_date DESC
                    ";      
        $qry_sql .= ($userOptions['forumPosts']>=1 && $userOptions['forumPosts']<=100) ? 
                    " LIMIT 0," .  $userOptions['forumPosts']
                    :" LIMIT 0,10";
        return($qry_sql);
    }
    catch(ExceptionHandler $e)
    {
        $e->ParseError($qry_sql);
    }
}
?>
```

I'm thinking that there is something here that isn't connecting with the post ID. For example, when I click on the first post in the list:

http://vi-control.net/community/index.php?threads/ORCHESTRAL-TOOLS-ANNOUNCES-SOLOISTS-SERIES--new-TECH-DEMOS.46965/

I see that it's aiming at the thread, 
index.php?threads/ORCHESTRAL-TOOLS-ANNOUNCES-SOLOISTS-SERIES--new-TECH-DEMOS

even if the post ID is there: #46965

When I click on it, sure enough it gets to the first post of that thread, and not the one I expected to find. So it's like it's showing me the latest THREAD that saw a new post, rather than take me to the post itself.

Does anyone understand any of this... :) Is there a correction, modification or addition I could make to fix this?

The original plugin can be found here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4jzfpfpcccjtrj6/eipSoftwareOnlineUsers_v1.2.5b.zip?dl=0

And the code I posted above cam from the file: qry_lastposts.php located in  eipSoftware\lastposts\qry.

Thank you for any help!

Regards,

Andre

Answer (score 0):

Andre, the "Post ID" that you mentioned (46965) is actually the thread ID. For the third "post" on that thread, your link would look like `http://vi-control.net/community/threads/46965/#post-3884651` where `#post-3884651` is the post ID.

Your MySQL query is selecting the:

```
                        thread.last_post_id             as lastpostid,
```

So you want your URLs to look like:

```
'http://vi-control.net/community/posts/'.$lastpostid.'/'
```

Instead of the current format which is for threads. If you wanted to have it look like the `threads/THREADID/#post-POSTID` from the start you'd also have to deal with pagination affecting the URL, which complicates things.

Comment: Thanks Adam! 

What I'm thinking is: it's pulling the POST TITLE from somewhere, couldn't I make the URL associated with the post title lead back to it, instead of having a code that brings me back to the THREAD?

Comment: @ Adam - You wrote: "Instead of the current format which is for threads. If you wanted to have it look like the threads/THREADID/#post-POSTID from the start you'd also have to deal with pagination affecting the URL, which complicates things." 

So how would I deal with the pagination, then? How complicated is it? If it's possible, cold I hire someone to do it for me?

Many thanks!!

Comment: @AndreLefebvre it changes based on the settings in your ACP. I suppose you would use that value to check how many pages worth of posts you have then append that number to the end of your URL. Is it worth it? I don't think so. Could you hire someone? Yeah, but if they had the know-how for this they'd probably charge you a pretty penny. End-users normally don't even see / notice these links (the URL in the addressbar will be changed automatically to the correct thread format) - so why bother?